# 404 error while trying to access Exchange 2013 ECP from one of two CAS servers

Tags: exchange-server-2013

I have been tasked with not only upgrading our environment from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2013 but to also implement redundancy by also deploying it to our Disaster Recovery site.  To this end here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Head Office has one CAS and one Mailbox server
DR Site has one CAS and one Mailbox server
I have managed to log into the CAS located at the Head Office and create a DAG, have database copies, etc.

Because I'm using a coexistence scenario I'm having to use `https://HeadOffice.mycorp.com/ecp/?ExchClientVer=15` and I'm able to log in and do what I need just fine.
However, when I got to `https://DrSite.mycorp.com/ecp/?ExchClientVer=15` I get to the login page but after I log in i get a 404 Error.

It should be noted that both sites are on different subnets.
I have also deleting the canary data and restarted the servers as per [Unable to access OWA or ECP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/777b51ee-330d-43cc-a56e-4614d44aed7b/unable-to-access-owa-or-ecp-something-went-wrong-or-500-unexpected-error?forum=exchangesvrclients)

One thing I have notices and that has already tripped me up once for anyone dealing with similar issue is that you have to be careful when following advice when you have the CAS and Mailbox roles on different servers.  Alot of people and instructions assume that both are on the same machine.  Took me a while to realize that when instructions say to do something with the "Exchange Back End" that they mean, on the Mailbox server.

I bring this up because I have also tried [Cannot access Outlook Web App or the EAC after you re-create the "owa" or "ECP" virtual directory on an Exchange Server 2013 Mailbox server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778897)
I get the impression based on what I have read that the 404 is being returned from the Exchange Back End (aka the Mailbox server) but in my scenario how can I tell which one?

Does anyone have any ideas of what else I can look at?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before but I started doing a side-by-side comparison between the two CAS servers in IIS and I've noticed something interesting, the Default Web Site on the CAS that I'm having problems with has a status of Unknown for the net.tcp, net.pipe,net.msmq, and msmq.formatname bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course the best resource on the web winds up answering my question.  As always, you just have to know what to look for.  In my case [IIS 7.5 / WCF - net.tcp status unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743896/iis-7-5-wcf-net-tcp-status-unknown) had the fix.

All I had to do was to change the application pool for the MSExchangeOWAAppPool from Integrated to Classic then back to Integrated (and recycled for good measure) and it started working.  I can now log into the ECP from both the head office and the DR site.

Answer (score 0):

For me on WINDOWS SERVER 2008 R2 STANDART reinstall (rerunning setup.exe of Exchange installation)  and checking box of Client Acces Role at Server Role Selection step solved problem. 
During first installation I left that checkbox unchecked...

[Find screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBD8z.jpg)